# In python how to receive and save image in HTTP post request without using requests and other libraries that are not installed in python

Tags: python, http, post, urllib2, urllib

I try to receive image from HTTP post request in python. I am using BaseHTTPHolder and do_POST() function. I try to receive image from localhost address http:127.0.0.1:8080/photo while running server on localhost. I tried to use code below, it saves photo but doesn't allow to open because photo is not received fully.

```
img = urllib2.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8080/photo').read()
content_length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length',0))
file_content = self.rfile.read(content_length)
with open('/Users/kasymhan/Desktop/sprint2/file01.jpg','wb') as s:
        s.write(file_content)
```

**EDIT**
My do_POST() function

```
def do_POST(self):
            url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/photo/file02.jpg'
            request_headers = self.headers
            content_length = request_headers.getheaders('content-length')
            length = int(content_length[0]) if content_length else 0
            file_content = self.rfile.read(length) 
            img = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
            with open('/Users/kasymhan/Desktop/sprint2/image.jpg','wb') as s:
                s.write(img)
```

Comment: Please include a larger chunk of your code to see how you're using the `do_POST()` function.

Answer (score -1):

Why not directly write the contents of the image to the output file:

```
import urllib2

url = "http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4105/5063092779_17b2133825_b.jpg"

img = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
with open('./image.jpg','wb') as s:
    s.write(img)
```

Comment: I am sending image from computer to server that is running on 127.0.0.1. I am not sure how to specify file in 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/photo' this url.